# How to move a list of folders?

Tags: shell, command-line, ssh, command

I have a list of about 200 folders that I need to move into a new folder.

I know how to move one folder at a time through command line, but is there a way to move all of them at once?

For example, I want to move all of these folders to a new folder:

```
folder
otherfolder
extras
helpdesk
support
```

Thanks for any help that anyone can give!

Comment: This might be better suited at http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `mv` is given more than one argument, the last one must be a directory, and all the previous ones are moved to that directory.

```
mkdir newfolder
mv folder otherfolder extras help desk support newfolder
```